# Passing a state from the asynchronous http call without blocking the thread

Tags: spring, reactive-programming, project-reactor

I would like to create a Flux which passes new state to next operation according to the future result it gets from in the current process.

I already implemented sth like this:

```java
public static Flux<MyResult> create(MyHttpClient myClient) {
        final MyGenerator generator = new MyGenerator(myClient);
        return Flux.generate(Optional::empty, generator);
}

private final static class MyGenerator implements BiFunction<Optional<String>, SynchronousSink<MyResult>, Optional<String>> {

        private final MyHttpClient myHttpClient;

        private MyGenerator(MyHttpClient myHttpClient) {
            this.myHttpClient = myHttpClient;
        }

        @Override
        public Optional<String> apply(Optional<String> lastState, SynchronousSink<Object> objectSynchronousSink) {
            MyResult myResult = lastState.map((ls) -> myHttpClient.blockingRequestWithState(ls)).orElseGet(() -> myHttpClient.blockingRequestForInitial());
            if (myResult.isFinished()) {
                sink.complete();
                return Optional.empty();
            }
            sink.next(myResult);
            return Optional.of(myResult.getLastState());
        }
    }
```

However, I would like to avoid blocking the thread by calling 'myHttpClient.blockingRequest...' methods and make the request asynchronously and pass this future value as the lastState.

Do you have any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: you have to rework blockingRequestWithState method in an asynchronous procedure. For this, you need to eliminate all blocking calls inside it, in particular, replace blocking network calls with non-blocking ones.

Comment: Yeah, but the thing I am asking that when I make it non-blocking how can I supply the last state (let's say it is CompletionStage) coming from the asynchronous call to the next iteration in the flux.

Comment: what is "next iteration in the flux"? Flux is subtype of Publisher, and CompletionStage is also a Publisher in some broad sense. Do you want to convert CompletionStage to Flux? Better convert it to a Mono. You can do it by standart means: https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#fromCompletionStage-java.util.concurrent.CompletionStage-

Comment: yeah, I mean the element will get emitted depending upon the state coming from the previous element. Before I tried to implement it in various ways by using Mono.fromCompletionStage like you also suggested, however, I couldn't succeed. 
You can find a sample code in the following link the thing I try to achieve (I replaced the logic of network calls with an async simple integer generation to give a better understanding of the flow): https://gist.github.com/cenkakin/b100d087f26d0c04045654fe9ab8f67a 
In this implementation, the flux is generating initial values over and over again.

Comment: Flux provides subscribers with a sequence of values. You want to make a sequence of asynchronous http requests. Do you want to provide the subscriber with all intermediate results of that requests, or with the latest result only? The latter task is simpler because to provide all the intermediate results, you have to take into account backpressure issues.

Comment: I need to provide each result of the requests to downstream and each result object affects the next result will be emitted from the next http request.

Comment: that is, requests should be made sequentially. Then simple loop would be more suitable than Flux or any other asynchronous and/or parallel facilities.